# Filter by max number in a column

Tags: python, pandas, filter, max

I have a forecast that reruns each week and gives the following output.
I'm looking to create a new dataframe with just the most recent forecast.

```
     Value  WeekNo
1    43     28
2    42     27
3    23     26
4    23     28
5    24     27
6    26     26
7    65     28
8    23     27
9    35     26
```

```
Desired Output;

   Value WeekNo
1  43    28
2  23    28
3  65    28
```

I have been using;

```
weekno = ['28'] 
new = df.loc[df['WeekNo'].isin(weekno)]
```

..but have to change the week number manually.
How would I use the above but to pull out the max week?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [8]: df[df["WeekNo"].max() == df["WeekNo"]]
Out[8]:
   Value  WeekNo
0     43      28
3     23      28
6     65      28
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
df.query("WeekNo == WeekNo.max()")
   Value  WeekNo
1     43      28
4     23      28
7     65      28
```